# objective C OSX - Delegate - calling a sub from another class (not as a instance)

Tags: objective-c

Im trying a delegate but its not working.
The changeView_ShowContact method will make a view controller to show up just fine. But when I call the changeView_ShowContact from another class it wont work.

```
@protocol callingActions_fromMainNavigation <NSObject>
    - (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact:(id)sender;
@end

**@interface Navigation_Main : NSViewController**
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <callingActions_fromMainNavigation> delegate;

**@implementation Navigation_Main** 
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"********************ShowContact");
    AddStuffViewController = [[pageContact alloc] initWithNibName:@"pageContact" bundle:nil];
    [AddStuffView addSubview:[AddStuffViewController view]]; //<This call here works ok.
}
```

.

```
@interface contacts : NSObject <callingActions_fromMainNavigation>

**@implementation contacts**
-(void)myMethodCall:(id)sender;
{
    Navigation_Main *NavMain = [[Navigation_Main alloc] initWithNibName:@"Navigation_Main.h" bundle:nil];
    [NavMain setDelegate:self];
    [self changeView_ShowContact:nil];
//I need to call the (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact in the Main Navigation. This 
//code is not working.
}

- (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact:(id)sender;
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a non-shared instance of a class (something that isn't a singleton), why would you ever expect a new initialized instance of a class to share a reference to any other reference?  That would be a disaster!  You need to get a valid reference to the view controller that (ideally) owns that `contacts` object, not try and init your own and pray for a major malloc() error.  I've fixed your code (including the name of some of the classes):

```
//Even delegates need a standard "namespace" prefix for safety
@protocol CFIContactsNavigation<NSObject>
    - (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact:(id)sender;
@end

// This is a terrible name for a class.  Categories are the only classes
// that should use underscores mid-name, and even then only when compiled
@interface CFIMainNavigationViewController : NSViewController
//delegates are **never** strong
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CFIContactsNavigation> delegate;

@implementation CFIMainNavigationViewController
//@synthesize delegate;  unnecessary

- (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"********************ShowContact");
    AddStuffViewController = [[pageContact alloc] initWithNibName:@"pageContact" bundle:nil];
    [AddStuffView addSubview:[AddStuffViewController view]]; //<This call here works ok.

    CFIContacts *contacts = [CFIContacts new];
    [self setDelegate:contacts];
    [contacts setNavMain:self];
}

//Again, terrible name for a class.  Also, it's missing an @end
@interface CFIContacts : NSObject <CFIContactsNavigation>

@property (nonatomic, weak) CFIMainNavigationViewController *navMain;

@end

@implementation CFIContacts
-(void)myMethodCall:(id)sender;
{
    //instance names are pascal-cased
    // CFIMainNavigationViewController *navMain = [[Navigation_Main alloc] initWithNibName:@"Navigation_Main.h" bundle:nil];
    [self.mainNav changeView_ShowContact:nil];
//I need to call the (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact in the Main Navigation. This 
//code is not working.
}

//Why the heck are there a pair of parenthesis *and* a semicolon?  
// this would never compile
- (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact:(id)sender { }

//...

@end
```